# How do I get Chrome Dev Tools to allow me to edit minified JavaScript in production?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, minify, production-environment

I need to test a fix, and only production data is failing (and a tangled nest of foreign keys prevent copying data down to test).

The JavaScript fix is simple, 2 or 3 lines to section_functions.min.js.

I open dev tools, click the sources tab, drill down to the file... edit it. I do a cntl+s, the star disappears from the file's tab in Dev Tools.

I then use the web app's interface in such a way that the altered function in that file should be invoked...

But in the console, I get my same error as before and it's telling me the exception is on /js/section_functions.min.js (old):1 .

I know that it's possible to edit the javascript live in this fashion, and I must be doing something boneheaded that is preventing it from using the modified version. What am I failing to do correctly?

Comment: Does the function that you are modifying have global scope?  If not then you're not editing the function that actually runs, but a declaration of it.

Comment: I believe that it does have global scope. Not a method of some object. Able to invoke it directly from the console with no namespacing.

Comment: I'm out of ideas then as you've described exactly what I do, and I've never had a problem with it.  I hope someone can help :)

Comment: Well, at least I know I'm not doing something too stupid. Wonder if I have some craptastic extension interfering with this...

Answer (score 1):

there is a usefull trick, add a sourcemap to your compressed js file so you can see and edit the code in beauty way.

other way faster to it is using the {} buton in the chrome tools it is in the bottom of the file in the left of line and column number

when you have it looking good you can edit it.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

- Set the breakpoint
- Refresh the page
- Redefine the function or variable
- Save the JavaScript file

[image: Edit JSLint source in Chrome DevTools Sources Panel]
**References**

- [Get Started with Debugging JavaScript in Chrome DevTools  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)
- [Debugging Chromium on Windows - The Chromium Projects](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/debugging-on-windows)
- [Featured DevTools Extensions - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/extensions-gallery)
- [Set Up Persistence with DevTools Workspaces  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/setup-workflow)
- [JavaScript Debugging Reference  |  Web  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/reference#edit)
- [Debugging Node.js with Chrome DevTools – Medium](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)